# How to access local variable in for loop through dictionary or dictionaries when only one dictionary is available?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a for loop going through a dictionary of dictionaries. It works just fine unless there is only one dictionary total.

Here's the gist of my method:

```
- (NSArray *)objectsFromJSON:(NSString *)jsonString error:(NSError **)error
{
    NSParameterAssert(jsonString != nil);

    // create JSON object
    NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *localError = nil;
    id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&localError];
    NSDictionary *dictionaryOfDictionaries = (id)jsonObject;

    // if not parsed successfully, error
    if(dictionaryOfDictionaries == nil)
    {
        if(error != NULL)
        {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:ErrorDomain code:MissingDataError userInfo:nil];
        }

        return nil;
    }

    // else create objects out of parsed data
    NSMutableArray *objectsArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(NSDictionary *objectDictionary in dictionaryOfDictionaries)
    {
        // required properties
        Obj *object = [[Obj alloc]
                            initWithName:objectDictionary[@"name"]
                            Street:objectDictionary[@"street"]
                            City:objectDictionary[@"city"]
                            State:objectDictionary[@"state"]
                          ];

        // if error, return
        if(object == nil)
        {
            if(!error)
            {
                *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:ErrorDomain code:MissingDataError userInfo:nil];
            }

            return nil;
        }

        // else add to array of objects created successfully
        [objectsArray addObject:object];
    }

    return [objectsArray copy];
}
```

As mentioned, this works fine - i.e. all of the `object`s are created successfully out of the `objectDictionary` - if there's more than one dictionary in `dictionaryOfDictionaries`. However, if there is just one dictionary, `objectDictionary` ends up being type `id` in the for loop (instead of type `Obj`), and trying to access its values, such as `objectDictionary[@"name"]` results in an error.

How do I most efficiently write this so the case of having one dictionary is handled?

Comment: What is the actual type of `objectDictionary` when there is only one dictionary?

Comment: What is the error in the one dictionary case?

Comment: I'm guessing that when there's only one dictionary returned to you, it isn't packaged in an array and is simply returned directly. You should check the type of `dictionaryOfDictionaries`.

Comment: @Paulw11 here's the error:

error: -[ObjectBuilderTests testBuildingOnlyOneObjectIsPossible] : failed: caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "-[__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9413b23de0"

Comment: @rmaddy here's the type:

(lldb) po [objectDictionary class]
__NSCFString

Comment: As the others have said - you are getting a single dictionary in this case, so your for loop is giving you strings, not dictionaries - so you get an unrecognised selector when trying to treat a string as a dictionary

Comment: @IanMacDonald here's the type of dictionaryOfDictionaries: (lldb) po [dictionaryOfDictionaries class]
__NSCFDictionary

Comment: @Paulw11 i see! so i should check if its of type string? and convert that string to a dictionary?

Comment: It would be better if whatever was giving you the JSONString was consistent and always wrapped your dictionaries in an outer dictionary (or better yet an array), but otherwise you can check the object class and process it appropriately

Comment: @Paulw11 gotcha. given i can't control what it returns, i guess it's processing for me. Or, pre-processing the JSON that's passed into that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the issue. When you have more than one dictionary, you actually get an array of dictionaries. In other words, `jsonObject` is really an `NSArray` containing each of the dictionaries.

When there is just one dictionary, `jsonObject` is just that one dictionary.

Change your code like this:

```
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&localError];
NSArray *arrayOfDictionaries = nil;
if (jsonObject == nil) {
    // handle error
} else if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    arrayOfDictionaries = jsonObject;
} else {
    arrayOfDictionaries = @[ jsonObject ];
}
```

Then change the `for` loop to:

```
for(NSDictionary *objectDictionary in arrayOfDictionaries)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Array from json response that would be dictionaries

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
 if (error)
    NSLog(@"JSONObjectWithData error: %@", error);

for (NSMutableDictionary *dictionary in array)
{
   //Do what you want to do 
}
```

Comment: same issue still occurred